# CSS inline-block white space

Tags: css

I need to render white space in inline-block but instead of white space, I will not render anything. I can not figure out where the CSS'm wrong.

CSS:

```css
.foo {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="foo">a</span><span class="foo"> </span><span>class="foo">b</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7dtevce/

Comment: What exactly do you want the result to be? https://jsfiddle.net/q7dtevce/3/, or…?

Comment: there is whitespace between a and b in your jsfiddle

Comment: yes i want that, thanks :-)

Comment: try &nbsp; instead of the space

Comment: you can use `&nbsp;`

Comment: LOL I was pasting an answer when all these comments were posted. too funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid whitespace being trimmed or otherwise altered in an element, you can use `white-space: pre-wrap`.

```css
.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7dtevce/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to force it to have layout by having your markup changed to this:

```
<span class="foo">a</span>
<span class="foo">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="foo">b</span>
```

TO see the differences, put a border around it, then remove it (the `&nbsp;`) 
as here: http://jsfiddle.net/q7dtevce/4/